# Virtualization not supported when attempting to run Docker for Windows on an AMD C-60

Tags: 64-bit, virtualization, docker, cpu-architecture, docker-for-windows

My Acer Aspire One, model [AO725](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/support-product/4253), doesn't support virtualization technology. Is there any alternative way to run Docker for Windows in this case?

- **Processor**: AMD C-60 APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics 1.00 GHz
- **System type** : 64-bit Operating System, x64-based processor
- **edition** : Windows 10 pro
- **version** : 1809
- **Hyper-V** : enable
- **virtualization** : disable

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: http://cpuboss.com/cpu/AMD-C-60 and http://cpu-world.com/CPUs/Bobcat/AMD-C%20Series%20C-60.html both indicate AMD-V is supported by the processor which gives you virtualization.  Do you meet all the system requirements of Docker for Windows? https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/ Have you installed Hyper-V? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/enable-hyper-v

Comment: If you are going to provide screenshots, you need to provide an English translation, for the text contained within.  **I can't tell what the screenshot actually indicates.**

Comment: @K7AAY I install Hyper-V but virtualization still disable.

Comment: That could be a feature to enable in the BIOS of your computer. Since you have not specified what your computer is, my old, I can't confirm that, but with the AMI BIOS popular with the systems I work on, it must be enabled in the BIOS.

Comment: I'm unable to activate virtualization in the BIOS, my processor does't support it.

Comment: @Azi_bel - According to several sources your CPU does support AMD-V but according to your own screenshots it's not currently enabled within the BIOS.

Comment: the BIOS setup page with the CPU name is useless. We already have that information from above. If the other pages have no settings for virtualization then it's simply because your BIOS doesn't allow you to enable virtualization. A lot of laptop BIOSes do that. If you're in that case then then only choices are updating the BIOS, or buying a new CPU

Comment: @Azi_bei, you're doing fine in providing information, we just need more. The MAIN section of BIOS/Setup probably has multiple menus beneath it. Please check those for a Virtualization or AMD-V setting. If you do not find it, mon ami, please look on the bottom of the laptop and find the plate or sticker with the serial number. It will also have a model number which is MUCH more useful than any marketing series number on the top or inside. If you cannot find a Virtualization or AMD-V setting in the BIOS menus under Main, please click [edit] and give us the make and model number.

Comment: @K7AAY There is no Advanced option available in the BIOS,The only available options are :Info, Main, Security,Boot and Exit.. I can't find virtualization or AMD-V setting.

Comment: We have done all that can be done. It's New (or Different) Hardware time if you really need to run Docker for Windows.

Comment: That let me find the Acer support page, which did not have (as other manufacturers such as Lenovo provides) any useful information about the BIOS menus.

Comment: I know this question is a bit old, but 2 things I like to mention anyway: 1) Acer is well-known to deliver computers with a dumbed down bios, where the Virtualization option is removed even though the hardware is capable. In that case you just can't use it. 2) In many Bios setups (not just Acer) the virtualization options are hiding in the Security menu. And in some cases are only visible if the system is configured for the UEFI "Secure Boot" feature. So playing around with settings may help.

Comment: I also have a AMD C60 but from Asus. The BIOS is incredibly sparse and doesn't provide any option to toggle virtualization. Bummer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any alternative way to run Docker for Windows in this case?

`Docker Desktop for Windows` requires hardware virtualization support.  It specifically requires the Hyper-V Windows Feature be enabled, which requires hardware virtilization.  If your hardware does not support AMD-V this required feature cannot be enabled.  There is no alternative method to use `Docker Desktop for Windows` without hardware virtualization support.  **You will have to upgrade your hardware in order to install and run `Docker Desktop for Windows`.**

> `Docker Desktop for Windows` requires the Hyper-V Windows feature which is not available on Windows Home

Source: [Windows Requirements](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/faqs/)

Answer (score 0):

Technically the C-60 cpu supports `AMD-V / AMD Virtualization technology`, although most laptop BIOS don't seem to provide any option to toggle it.

Although I lucked out on Windows, funnily enough on Linux it works !

After installing `sudo apt-get install cpu-checker` I ran the `kvm-ok` command:

```
root@box:~# kvm-ok
INFO: Your CPU supports KVM extensions
INFO: /dev/kvm does not exist
HINT: sudo modprobe kvm_amd
KVM acceleration can NOT be used
```

Then it was just a matter of modprobing `kvm_amd`:

```
root@box:~# sudo modprobe kvm_amd
root@box:~# kvm-ok
INFO: Your CPU supports KVM extensions
INFO: /dev/kvm exists
KVM acceleration can be used
```

On Windows I have no clue, but anyhow wanted to show you it's technically possible on this little cpu.